# passing html passthrough from apex to selectoptions

Tags: controller, visualforce-component

I'm trying to pass through some additional information via the html- passthrough on apex:selectoptions from the controller.

Ie I need it to output:

`<apex:selectOption html-data-range="h"  itemValue="RW" itemLabel="Running" />`

because I use the data attribute to change some front-end stuff.

is there any way to set the html-passthrough value from the controller?

Comment: Unfortunately, SelectOption is a *final* class, and doesn't have any way to express additional values beyond "value" and "label." The only clear workaround I can think of would be to use normal HTML constructs (e.g. emit a normal `select` with `option` children) by using a wrapper class to expose the passthrough parameters (at which point, they're just normal HTML attributes, don't include the `html-`). Then, wire up an onchange JavaScript event that would populate a backing field (e.g. `<apex:inputHidden value="{!selectedOptions}" id="mySelectionValues" />`. Let's see if anyone has an idea.

Comment: that's a pretty good idea.  My other workaround thought would be to also just dump the fields to the page via a serialized JSON object and then have the frontend pull the extra values out by looking up the selected value.

Comment: JSON serialization will work. I have tried previously in some use cases to render dropdowns. You can serialize JSON and assign to a string property in controller, it will be available in javascript in page.

Comment: I would think writing your own `CustomSelectOption` wrapper would be the simplest solution. You would need to use the html `select` tag but no JavaScript.